# How to use find command to search for multiple extensions

Tags: find, regular-expression

I can get all `jpg` images by using:

```
find . -name "*.jpg"
```

But how can I add `png` files to the results as well?

Comment: Related: [`find -name` pattern that matches multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1133698/55075) at SO

Comment: i dig `find . | egrep '.jpg|.png'` a lot.

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Use the `-o` flag between different parameters.

`find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)` works like a charm.

**NOTE** There *must* be a space between the bracket and its contents or it won't work.

Explanation:

- `-type f` - only search for files (not directories)
- `\(` & `\)` - are needed for the `-type f` to apply to all arguments
- `-o` - logical OR operator
- `-iname` - like `-name`, but the match is case insensitive

Comment: Do you need the parentheses. The command works for me without them. Are they needed for some shells?

Comment: @miked The command will "work" without them, yes, but you'd wind up getting hits on directories that end in .png as well as files that end with .jpg, which is not exactly what was intended.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! The `type -f` does not extend and apply to both expressions without the parentheses, So, `find ./ -type f -iname \*.jpg -o -type f -iname \*.png` also works ... although it's two characters longer :-)

Comment: It's a matter of operator precedence. Just like `a * b + c` is different from `a * (b + c)`

Comment: Thanks, and I have rewritten `a * (b + c)` as `a * b + a * c` with:  
`find ./ -type f -iname \*.jpg -o -type f -iname \*.png`

Answer (score 149):

You can combine criteria with `-o` as [suggested by Shadur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4949/shadur). Note that `-o` has lower precedence than juxtaposition, so you may need parentheses.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png'
find . -mtime -7 \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \)  # all .jpg or .png images modified in the past week
```

On Linux, you can use `-regex` to combine extensions in a terser way. The default regexp syntax is Emacs ([basic regexps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) plus a few extensions such as `\|` for alternation); there's an option to switch to [extended regexps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions).

```
find -regex '.*\.\(jpg\|png\)'
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(jpg|png)'
```

On FreeBSD, NetBSD and OSX, you can use `-regex` combined with `-E` for extended regexps.

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png)'
```

Comment: It's always better to use `-iname` instead of `-name` — then you will also capture `image.JPG` and `image.PnG`

Comment: You can use `-iregex` instead of `-regex` to ignore case

Answer (score 64):

This is more correct:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)$'
```

Comment: Why do you say it is "more" correct?

Comment: @Kevin I guess because `-iregex` matches `jpg` as well as `JPG Jpg jpG` and such. I think the `$` isn't needed.

Comment: This works fine on [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW).

Comment: First, you omitted the search folder as first argument which will throw an error. Secondly, on OSX escaping the parenthesis will not work, and this should be used instead: `find -E . -iregex '.*\.(jpg|png|gif)'` as shown in @sorin's answer.

Comment: Much better than the stupid `-o` operator and it's more correct since you have to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: `-o` isn't stupid; it does exactly what the `or` operator is supposed to do. And the "right" tool for the job is whatever gets the job done.

Comment: Also, this version will also yield *directories* that end in any of those extensions, so it's arguably *less* correct than my solution.

Answer (score 22):

To make it clear, the only option that works on Linux, Unix and macOS flavour is:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|png)'
```

That's because the OS X version is a little bit different, but that's important to write things that go well on most platforms.

Comment: -E flag is not valid for find on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The -E flag is not valid on [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) either (at least the version/configuration I tried it on (default configuration for a particular version)).

Comment: Which part of `-type f \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg\)` does not work on OSX?

Comment: Can confirm `-type f \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg\)` does work on OSX

Answer (score 3):

If only files are needed:

```
find ./ -type f -regex '.*\.\(jpg\|png\)$'
```

For example, this will not match a directory named "blah.jpg".