# Format for iname in Find operation

Tags: find

When using `find` what is the correct format to say "Find files that end in .jpg OR .png"?

Is it as simple as using the `|` operator/character?

```
find -iname "*.jpg|*.png"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use find command to search for multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions)

Answer (score 2):

No.

You need to use `-o` (OR) in `find` like:

```
find \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' \)
```

Your one would be close to correct if you are matching Regex:

```
find -iregex ".*\(jpg\|png\)"
```

Or using extended Regex:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -iregex ".*(jpg|png)"
```

Comment: +1. FYI, `-regextype egrep` also gives you extended regular expressions with GNU extensions (like `\w` and `\b` and `{n,m}` intervals)  and is shorter to type.  see `pinfo find --node 'Regular Expressions'`

Comment: @cas Thanks..On my GNU `find` 4.4.2 (Ubuntu 14.04) it is `posix-egrep`

Comment: mine is the findutils 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 package in debian sid. (although, oddly, `find --version` says 4.7.0-git).  I've been using `-regextype awk` until recently, but that doesn't support the gnu extensions.