# How can I do an "or" search with find?

Tags: find, regular-expression

Essentially, I want to know how to run 2 (or more) find commands in one - an "or" search rather than an "and":

```
find . -name "*.pem"
find . -name "*.crt"
```

Comment: Also: [How to use find command to search for multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`find`’s “or” operator is `-o`:

```
find . -name "*.pem" -o -name "*.crt"
```

It is short-circuiting, *i.e.* the second part will only be evaluated if the first part is false: a file which matches `*.pem` won’t be tested against `*.crt`.

`-o` has lower precedence than “and”, whether explicit (`-a`) or implicit; if you’re combining operators you might need to wrap the “or” part with parentheses:

```
find . \( -name "*.pem" -o -name "*.crt" \) -print
```

In my tests this is significantly faster than using a regular expression, as you might expect (regular expressions are more expensive to test than globs, and `-regex` tests the full path, not only the file name as `-name` does).

Comment: Even better.  Simpler and easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

While I was typing up this question, it occurred to me that find uses globbing rather than regex by default.  But I bet there's a way to use regex!

Sure enough...I had to change the regextype to use posix-extended but that got me what I wanted.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*pem|.*crt"
```

Qaplah!

Comment: Run a couple of finds with `time` at the start to analyse whether you're faster using regex or wildcards. If you're searching over files might be worth using `locate`.

Comment: `".*pem|.*crt"` finds a name that ends with pem or crt, not a file with those extensions. You'll need `.*\.pem|.*\.crt` for that. But using regex for this isn't a good method anyway

Comment: @phuclv Actually, since the expression is not anchored to the end of the pathname, it may match anywhere, even in a parent directory name.  This is because `-regex` is applied to the whole pathname and because unanchored regular expressions may match anywhere in the given string.

Comment: Regular-expression matching is a non-standard extension provided by some, but not necessarily all, implementations of `find`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes that has already been mentioned by Kusalananda above]