# Find + regex: looking for a file name with multiple extensions, but missing the basic filename.jpg

Tags: find, regular-expression

I'm both a regex & SE Unix and Linux newbie, so I hope I'm doing everything right.

I'm looking for files that have a name inside of the filename, and could have different extensions. I based my initial trials on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions#answer-15337) (the linux part) and my basic understanding of find and regexes, but with limited success.

I tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/512XUz/1/): `.*filename[^/].*\.(jpg|xcf|png|jpeg)`, which inside `find` looked like this `find . -iregex '.*filename.*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)$'`. 
The idea was to exclude the appearance of "filename" inside directory names, hence the "without forward slashes" `[^/]` part of the regex, but it excludes the most basic (and necessary) format, e.g. filename.jpg

I also tried `find . -type f -iregex '.*filename.*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)$'`, but I have the feeling that using regexes might bypass the `-type` flag, because I still get all the directories in my results.

Could you share some light?

Comment: Bit confused here - you mention `[^/]` but then don't seem to use it; I suspect what you want is `[^/]*` (**not** `[^/].*`)

Comment: @steeldriver nice double find, thank you. Would you mind explaining the difference? I thought that the `[^/]` would prevent the regex to find patterns that had a slash in it, but then how does the simple quantifier alone allow for other characters to be there? Or the quantifier in this case means "find any char but a /" (which would then be equivalent to the `.`, but for the exception)?

Comment: `[^/]*` is a (possibly empty) sequence of characters none of which is `/` whereas `[^/].*` means a single character that is not `/` followed by a (possibly empty) sequence of *any* characters (which may include `/`)

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks a lot. I think I was confused by the implicit assertion: I keep thinking in terms of "not /" (to which I was trying to add an "every character" notation, as I would in normal programming, say in python or JS), and forget that the `[^/]` actually means "every kind of character but /".

Comment: @steeldriver You should really have made it an answer, otherwise the question shows up as unanswerd, in fact i've started writing an answer, and then noticed that basically i was saying what you have said already.