# find - Globbing with disjunction

Tags: find, wildcards

I've previously written a script that searches a directory tree for .h and .c files and then runs clang-format on them:

```bsh
find $directory -name '*.[hc]' -exec clang-format -i {} \;
```

This works just as expected.  Now I'd like to add .cpp files to the search.  However, neither

```bsh
-name '*.{[hc],cpp}'
```

nor

```bsh
-name '{*.[hc],*.cpp}'
```

work.  That is, they find no files.

I know that I could get my logic to work if I used `find`'s `-o` option.  However, there must be a way to do this with a single `-name` directive.

Comment: If your implementation of `find` supports -regex you can do `find
. -regex "\./.*\.[c|h]"`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Note that `[c|h]` would match one character from the set `c`, `|`, and `h`.

Comment: @they: ah, right, it should be `find . -regex  "\./.*\.[c,h]"`

Comment: Just another re-spin of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk And `[c,h]` matches a comma. You mean `(c|h)`, but that misses out on `cpp`, so you end up with `(c|h|cpp)`.  Unfortunately though, rugelar expressions are non-standard when used with `find` and we don't even know what Unix the user is using let alone what `find` implementation thay have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-name` supports patterns that are not unlike shell globs, but it doesn't support braces (which the GNU find man page explicitly mentions), nor ksh-style extended globs.

But many `find`s support the `-regex`, and you may be able to use that. Depending on what regex dialects your `find` supports that is, as standard basic regexes *don't* support alternation.

With GNU find, this should work:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(c|h|cpp)'
```

(Also note that the match there is a match against the whole path, not just the filename part, but if you're matching just the final suffix of the filename, that's not going to be an issue.)

Answer (score 11):

The patterns used with the `-name` predicate in `find` are standard filename globbing patterns.  What you are trying to use is a brace expansion, which `find` does not support.

Note that there is no *single* standard globbing pattern that matches filenames that end with `.c`, `.h` or `.cpp`.

You might have wanted to use something like `'*.'{c,h,cpp}`, which expands to `*.c`, `*.h`, and  `*.cpp`, but that does not include the `-name` predicate nor the `-o`.

The next thing to try is `'-o -name "*.'{c,h,cpp}'"'`, but this expands to the three strings `-o -name "*.c"`
`-o -name "*.h"`, and
`-o -name "*.cpp"`.  This also can't be used as you would have to split them on spaces to get `find` to recognize the separate substrings (and remove the `-o` from the first one). It would possibly work with `eval` though, but it seems like more hassle than it's worth.

Instead of that, you may use *two* `-name` tests with an OR in-between:

```bsh
find  "$directory" -type f \( -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.cpp' \) \
    -exec clang-format -i {} +
```

This uses two `-name` tests as described earlier (`-o` is the OR operator), and also calls `clang-format` as few times as possible by passing batches of found pathnames to the tool rather than invoking it once for each file.

With a tiny extra bit of programming, you may store all the filename suffixes that you want to pick up in a list, and create the needed `find` expression from that.

Since you did not mention what shell you're using, I'm doing this for the POSIX `sh` shell:

```bsh
set -- c h cpp

for suffix do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
    shift
done

shift # shifts off the initial "-o"

find "$directory" -type f \( "$@" \) -exec clang-format -i {} +
```

or

```bsh
set --
for suffix in c h cpp; do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
done

shift

find "$directory" -type f \( "$@" \) -exec clang-format -i {} +
```

The list that `"$@"` expands to in this example would be the equivalent of

```bsh
-name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp'
```