# How to replace all matched strings in the files recursively?

Tags: text-processing, macos, replace, recursive

There are about 50 HTML/js files in the folder name site,

some of the files contain (below lines are combined from files)

```
    {"rendered":"http:\/\/localhost:4542\/?page_id=854"}
                 http:\/\/localhost:4542\/wp-content\/uploads\/2022\/09\/
           src=\"http:\/\/localhost:4542\/wp-content\/uploads\/2022\/09\/B
                 http:\/\/localhost:4542\/wp-content\/uploads\/2022\/09\/A
replies":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/localhost:4542\/en\/wp-json
```

Any tool/ commands to replace `http:\/\/localhost:4542` to `https:example.com` recursively in all files of a folder?

Working on a macOS now.

Comment: Macos has no some gui editor with find/replace in files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the command `find` with `-exec` argument:

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -regex '.*\.\(js\|html\)' -exec sed -i 's#http:\\/\\/localhost:4542#https:example.com#g' {} +
```

On Mac Os you can use a similar syntax:

```
find /path/to/folder -E -type f -regex '.*\.(js|html)' -exec sed -i '.bak' 's#http:\\/\\/localhost:4542#https:example.com#g' {} +
```

I really hope that works, I don't have a Mac to test it, but it should work.
On Mac Os when you specify the `-i` option the backup file name extension is required. You can use any value instead of '.bak'

Credits:

[How to use find command to search for multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions),

[sed command with -i option failing on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux)

**Note:** I'm not sure if this code will work in Mac Os, but you can try it too:

```
find /path/to/folder -iname "*.html" -o -iname "*.js" -exec sed -i 's#http:\\/\\/localhost:4542#https:example.com#g' {} +
```

Comment: find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: @user95432 Ok! I just saw you are on Mac OS. I will edit the post to use `find` in this os.

Comment: I don't find it works since files are unchanged.

Comment: @user95432 I searched and I saw that in Mac Os the `sed` command works differently in some ways.

Comment: @user95432 I edited again, try to test it. The problem was with `sed -i`

Comment: In place editing without backup with the `sed` of FreeBSD/macos is with `sed -i '' 'sed-code' file`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the tip! I guess these basic commands follow the same syntax for both operating systems. I also guess these problems are part of the POSIX compliant.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, POSIX `sed` doesn't support `-i`. Both GNU and FreeBSD added a `-i` to their respective `sed` inspired by perl's independendly in the early 2000s, unfortunately with incompatible interface, so there's little hope it will be standardised by POSIX soon. The GNU API (which most other implementations have copied including some other BSDs) is also incompatible with the POSIX option parsing which doesn't support options with optional arguments like GNU's `-i` / `-i.back` does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks again for the answer. All this information is useful, I don't know much about POSIX but I really have to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Portably:

```
LC_ALL=C find . '(' -name '*.[Jj][Ss]' -o \
                    -name '*.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]' -o \
                    -name '*.[Hh][Tt][Mm]' \
                ')' -exec perl -pi -e '
  s{\Qhttp:\/\/localhost:4542\E}{https:example.com}g' {} +
```

Note that it ends up rewriting even the files that have nothing to replace.

With GNU `grep`/`xargs` or compatible (and here a shell with brace expansion support to avoid too much typing), that can be avoided with:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -r --include='*.'{'[jJ][sS]','[Hh][Tt][Mm]'{,'[Ll]'}} \
  -Fl --null 'http:\/\/localhost:4542' . |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e '
    s{\Qhttp:\/\/localhost:4542\E}{https:example.com}g'
```

Except maybe for the `-r` option to `xargs` which you can remove without too much harm (just a perl warning if `grep` finds not file), it should also work on macos whose `grep` has copied most of the GNU API.

Comment: I really liked this answer. I had a doubt about `LC_ALL` and just found your answer in another question.

Comment: I spent 30+ years working on a system (which still exists, I just don't work there any longer) that only has the mandatory POSIX tools and we weren't allowed to install any others. We also occasionally see question on SO (I don't recall seeing any here) where people also say that's all they can have so a solution involving `perl` isn't entirely portable across Unix systems (which I assume is what you meant by "Portably").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to locate all files of certain type (e.g. `*.txt`) in the given folder (e.g. `.`), and then feed them into a `sed` command using `xargs`:

```
find .  -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/http:\\\/\\\/localhost:4542/https:example.com/g'
```

Note the escaping of the slashes in above.

Comment: if our files are not type specified, we can just use  -name '*' ?

Comment: @user95432 yes, you can use -name '*' if type is not specified.

Comment: Rather than `-name '*'`, just don't use `-name` at all in that case

Comment: Rather than having to escape all your `/`s, just don't use `/` as the sed delimiter, e.g. use `#` as in `s#http://local#foo#` instead of `s/http:\/\/local/foo/`